# Format the output of commands

Tags: bash, text-formatting, system-information

I am currently trying to use Plink to run a few commands on a linux server to monitor a couple of things on it such as the disk space, memory, cpu usage.
I have the commands that I want to use but I want to format the output that I get to something a little friendlier to read. 
This is the commands I am using inside my batch file.

```
 FOR /F "" %%G IN (C:\Users\username\Desktop\ip_list.txt) DO "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh -batch username@%%G -pw password "hostname; df | fgrep '/dev/'; free -h; top -bn2 | grep 'Cpu(s)';"
```

and here is the output that i get 
[image]

Basically, I would like to just add some lines in between the individual command outputs to make this a tiny bit easier to read. Is this possible without writing the output to a text file?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding **echo ""** in the middle of the commands where the space is required.

> Here are some example.

1. Adding new line in the middle.

**Example:**

```
 df | fgrep '/dev/'; echo ""; free -h
```

**output**

```
 tmpfs                                    16334344       55772  16278572   1% /dev/shm

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        4.0G         21G        346M        6.0G         26G
Swap:           15G        2.3M         15G
```

2. Adding detail of the command.

### Recommended

**Example:**

```
echo "==================" ; echo "This is output of df"; echo "==================" ;df | grep '/dev/shm' ; echo ""; echo "==================" ; echo "This is output of Free"; echo "==================";free -h
```

**Output:**

```
==================
This is output of df
==================
tmpfs                                    16334344       55772  16278572   1% /dev/shm

==================
This is output of Free
==================
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        4.0G         21G        359M        6.0G         26G
Swap:           15G        2.3M         15G
```

Comment: this is actually perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Learning is the key!

Comment: The quoted empty string argument is not needed, a simple `echo;` will do.

Comment: yea i actually ended up having to use && instead of ; in my script because it kept taking the ; as part of the echo instead of ending the command. Still great idea to use echo that i hadn't thought of though

Answer (score 0):

```
    Instead of displaying whole df command output i Wrote below script to find only if disk space crosses threshold (here i assuming threshold as 90%) and also included current memory usage percentage details

    Here is the code



      df -Ph| awk 'NR>1'| sed "s/%//g"| awk '($(NF-1) >90){print "Disk space utilized is" "  "$(NF-1)"%" " for partition" " "$NF}'|sed '1i Below are partition details of hosts where disk utilized crossed 90%\n'| sed '$s/.*/&\n=============================================================================/g';free  | awk '/Mem/{print $0}'| awk '{print $3/$2*100}'| sed '1i below are current memory usage percentage of host'



Sample output
Below are partition details of hosts where disk utilized crossed 90%

Disk space utilized is  100% for partition /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
Disk space utilized is  100% for partition /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
Disk space utilized is  100% for partition /snap/core/6531
Disk space utilized is  100% for partition /snap/gnome-calculator/260
Disk space utilized is  100% for partition /snap/gnome-logs/37
Disk space utilized is  100% for partition /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
=============================================================================
below are current memory usage percentage of host
39.2084
```

Comment: can you explain this code, please?